# Does a NodeJS server use multithreading?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, request, listen

I have a question about nodeJS (specifically with regards to version 9).  Using this project -- https://github.com/howardchung/jsminer, I'm running a nodeJS server, if that is the right word.  I spin it up on my command lien by running

```
node index.js
```

This is the only process I run.  Within the "index.js" file, express is used to create endpoints on which to listen, for instance

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.get('/work', function(req, res) {
    console.log("client requested work!");
    //send constructed block to client
    //client mines block
    //when client succeeds, client hits /submit
    res.json({
        result: curr_block
    });
});
```

If I were to call

```
http://localhost:5000/work
```

at the same time, does one call get blocked until the other call completes or are they handled simultaneously.  In other words, is multithreading enabled?

Comment: If your application is CPU-bound, you can use [Socketnaut](https://github.com/faranalytics/socketnaut) (multithreading) or [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) (multiprocessing) to scale the main module.  Socketnaut has an [example](https://github.com/faranalytics/socketnaut/tree/main/examples/socketnaut_express) specific to Express apps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some of it's underlying C++ components do but that capability is not exposed to you so you can't write threaded code yourself. The Javascript language itself doesn't provide support for threads.

To take advantage of multiple CPU's you can either spawn separate child processes or run a lot of parallel instances of the same process.

In other words you cant do [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)); but you can still do [multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing).

> ...does one call get blocked until the other call completes or are they handled simultaneously.

They are *accepted* in parallel, assuming your requests are primarily [I/O-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) (use the database, filesystem etc..) instead of [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) (perform encryption, decryption, compression etc..).

Node.js offers a type of pseudo-concurrency facilitated by using an [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and the programmer writing code in an [Event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) style (callbacks, Promises etc...), instead of creating separate threads for each request.

An oversimplification would be like this:

- Request A arrives and is put on the event queue.
- Request A requests data from the database.
- Request B arrives and is put on the event queue.
- Request B requests data from the database.
- Request B's database request arrives and request B is served with data.
- Request A's database request arrives and request A is served with data.

As you can see, Node accepts concurrent requests and serves each when necessary. It doesn't stop accepting incoming requests until another is served. It's [non-blocking](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/).

However the above scenario is a primarily I/O-bound example, where the Node.js concurrency model shines.

In contrast, if your requests are primarily CPU-bound (instead of I/O bound) then you *freeze* the single thread (remember Node.js is single-threaded) it runs on, requests cannot be accepted and your server "freezes" for the duration of that single request CPU computation.

> ...In other words, is multithreading enabled?

I *assume* that a lot of Node's underlying libraries ([libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) for example) do use multiple threads, however the ability to directly control threads is not exposed to the user (although in theory you can write native [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_c_addons) where you can harness multithreading).

If you're worried that you're not utilising all CPU cores, you should look into the [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to spin up multiple Node.js server processes. In this case the problem is taken off your hands; the O/S scheduler should, in most cases, spread the processes across available cores; this however is called *multi-processing*, not multithreading.

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile your "JavaScript is single threaded" and "it won't block requests" statements.  If I only have one process (e.g. "node.index.js") and two requests come in simultaneously, how is it able to process both of them?  If it were processing both simulaneously, isn't it acting in a threaded fashion?

Comment: It won't ever *process* both of them simultaneously. This is an oversimplification but think of it as that it will accept the request, mark it as pending and when it's ready it will serve it. In the meantime, other requests can be accepted. Perhaps reading up on the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) will clear things up.

Comment: @NikKyriakides how can i make my node.js Express.js Application Multi Threading..?

Comment: @usama AFAIK the most straightforward way would be to write a [C++ Node module](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that uses multiple threads which you can the require in your Node.js code,

Comment: @NikKyriakides Thanks for so quick reply i have tried this solution of clustering 

https://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/ 

If you can let me know if this works or not then it will be great.

Thanks again.

Comment: @usama That's not multithreading. It's *multiprocessing*. Multithreading means you have  shared memory. The cluster module just starts concurrent Node.js processes that don't share memory. You can still send data in between them using some sort of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) but again; you can't call that multithreading. If your basic requirement is that you simply want to take advantage of multi-core CPU's and you're not interested in scaling a *specific computation* across multiple CPU cores then using cluster is the right tool.

Comment: Thanks @NikKyriakides for explaining this to me Your explanation has really increased my knowledge Thanks again.